# Is IFI compatible with tempdb growth?

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

Is IFI ([Instant File Initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175935.aspx)) compatible with *tempdb* growth? Recently I needed to increase my *tempdb* by 40 Gb and it took 15+ minutes to complete. I verified that the user had already been added to *Perform Value Maintenance Task* and also verified that other user databases took seconds to complete.

I didn't find any documentation or link that would have in-depth IFI details with regard to *TempDB*. I really appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes,

Instant File Initialization works on TempDB Data files.  As with any other database, it doesn't work on the log file.  See [Aaron's Blog Post](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/io-subsystem/ifi-tempdb-setup) to see where he shows IFI working with TempDB via setup.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I am going to try it again to add more 40 GB and let see what happens. I also involved sysadmin team to look for read/writes.